# If we can make a field static should we do that?

Tags: java, static

My question is about making fields static in Java. Should we really do that every time we can do that? For example, the value of the potential static instance doesn't depend on the instance itself and is not going to be changed as long as the state of some instance's changed.

Comment: Do what makes most sense.  Not simply whatever you *can* do.

Comment: It sounds like it is easier to make it static, so why not?

Comment: @dotvav That's exactly what I'm asking about. Should I really do that? Or maybe not..

Comment: The answer boils down to what you mean by "we **can** do that". If you **can** do that without breaking your data model in any way, then it may be fine. But there are many ways in which your data model may be broken, depending on the visbility, usage and mutability of the field. The last one is the most important here: Introducing a global mutable state is generally a bad idea, due to possible unforeseen side-effects and glitches due to multithreading etc. So usually, a field should **not** be `static`, **unless** it's also `final`, but there may be (few) exceptions to this rule.

Answer (score 2):

`Static` fields belong to a class, hence shared by all the objects of that `class`, so memory usage is less... If you  want the field to be shared be shared between objects then yes you can do it.. If you declare the field as `public` and `static`, then it is globally available for everyone.

Now this has a Problem...

Say you are doing some execution with a `static` field and that is shared by all the objects... So if any object changes that value then it is changed in all the objects as the field is shared by every object... Which can ruin your execution and program drastically...

Now what i think is, it depends on what you have to do... if it requires to make field static then by all means do that... But prefer making fields non-static due to the problem i mentioned above..

Comment: Just because it won't change by any instance does not mean it should be marked final. It's value might be set based on something originally read from a file or who knows. Just because the instances don't update it doesn't mean it's a constant. Also it's not fair to call it a "glitch." It's not, static fields are shared. It's doing exactly what it's supposed to. Glitch implies a bug.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare instance variables, they take up memory for each instance. So if there are going to be 2,000 instances of an object, and you have a 32bit variable, that's 8KB of wasted memory. On the other hand, if it's static, it is only created once for the class, so instead of using 8KB, we use 1B.

Whether or not that matters depends on the situation. Working in an embedded system, I'm going to do everything I can to save that 8KB. On a reasonable desktop, I probably don't care as much.

I guess my question is, are you saying it **likely won't** change or it **won't** change. If there's a possibility someone's going to want to change it, or its value will be associated with the state of an instance, it should NOT be static. If it is 100% the same for every instance, I'd say it should be static.

However, I'll always add the caveat, do what seems to make the code most readable and makes the most sense in your situation. Since we're speaking hypothetically, it's hard to say with certainty what you should do in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really have to save memory, either make the field a constant by declaring it `static final` or leave it as it is.

In my experience, static non-final fields will only get you in trouble because of unforeseen side-effects which are usually very hard to find.

Comment: I don't like this logic. By this logic NEVER use threads. Synchronization issues and race conditions lead to unforeseen side effects and are usually very hard to find. The reality is, it comes down to knowing what you're doing. It's not inherently bad. Non final static fields are just fine if used correctly. If used incorrectly they can be dangerous... Just like dozens of other language features.

Comment: The main difference between static non-final fields and multi-threading is, that I don't see any benefit in using the former (aside from memory usage). But as you said, multi-threading is hard to get right, too, so I for one stay as far away from it as I can. Sometimes though, the benefits outweigh the drawbacks. I don't see a scenario where that is true for static non-final fields.

Comment: I work on embedded systems where we sometimes have 64kb of memory for the whole system. Every byte counts. I can't afford to waste them because I don't want to make things static.

Comment: That is why I started my answer with "unless you really have to save memory".

Answer (score 0):

By the fact that you added the following in your question:

> For example, the value of the potential static instance doesn't depend on the instance itself and is not going to be changed as long as the state of some instance's changed.

I think you know what you are doing.  A lot of people say to not use static, but what they are really saying is, "if you do not know what you are doing, then do not use static."  But as long as you understand that the static field belongs to the class and not the instance and hence realize and calculation the ramifications of that, then go ahead and do it.

For example I like to put our log4j Logger's as static final fields.  They are final, and named after the class, and do not throw an exception that needs to be dealt with.  So in that scenario it is better for the memory footprint to just have one of these Loggers versus a seprate one for each instance.

One of the big issues, and I mentioned it above, is whether the initialization of that static field has a potential exception that must be dealt with.  Many times that is the one point the last hurdle that forces me to make a field non-static.